# How can I add a different scale on my x-axis and how to make my legend smaller

Tags: r, legend

I want to upgrade the style of my base R graph
[image]
As you can see my x-axis doesn't cover everything and my legend is in comparisson with the figure way too big. How can I make my x-axis larger and my legend smaller (I have made some subsets for immature, female and male)

```
hist(Immature$Diameter, prob=TRUE ,breaks= seq(55,125, by=5), ylim=c(0,0.05), las=1, xlim=c(55,125), col=rgb(0,1,0,1/2), main="", xlab= "Diameter", ylab="Density")
hist(Female$Diameter, prob=TRUE, add=TRUE, breaks= seq(55,125, by=5), col=rgb(1,0,0,1/2))
hist(Male$Diameter, prob= T,breaks=seq(55,125, by=5), add=T, col=rgb(0,0,1,1/2)) #prob=T of freq=F (geeft probability densiteit weer) zelfde


x=seq(55,125,0.01)
curveImmature2<-curve(dnorm(x,mean=mean(Immature$Diam), sd=sd(Immature$Diam)), add= TRUE, col=rgb(0,1,0,1/2), lwd=2)
curveFemale2 <- curve(dnorm(x,mean=mean(Female$Diam), sd=sd(Female$Diam)), add= TRUE, col= rgb(1,0,0,1/2), lwd=2)
curveMale2 <- curve(dnorm(x, mean=mean(Male$Diam), sd=sd(Male$Diam)), add= TRUE, col=rgb(0,0,1,1/2), lwd=2)

legend(50,0.05,c('Immature', 'Female', 'Male'), lty = c(1,1,1), lwd=c(2.5,2.5,2.5), col=c(rgb(0,1,0,1/2),rgb(1,0,0,1/2) ,rgb(0,0,1,1/2) ))
```

Comment: 1) Remove the default scale and add one manually (see `help("axis")`). 2) Increase the size of your device / plot window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't provide any data to run your code on, I will use an example from the `hist` function instead.  Let's say this was your code to begin with

```
hist(islands)
legend("top", letters[1:3], lty=1, col=c("red", "blue", "green"))
```

Use the `xaxt` argument to `hist` (`?par`) to draw the histogram without an x-axis.  Then add a custom x-axis, specifying the tick mark and labels you want with the `axis` function.  Use the `cex` argument to `legend` (`?par`) to reduce the size of the legend.

```
hist(islands, xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=seq(0, 20000, 2000))
legend("top", letters[1:3], lty=1, col=c("red", "blue", "green"), cex=0.7)
```